# dd - Backup MBR/partition table and first partition

Tags: linux, bash, dd

I have been provided with a 3.8GB SD card image meant to be flashed to a 4GB SD card for booting a customized version of Raspian OS on the RaspBerry PI dev board. It has a first primary partition that is FAT32 that holds a bootloader, and another partition of a custom type that holds the OS.

I am able to boot the PI off the SD card with this image deployed on it, modify its contents while the board is running, then shut down the board.

I'd like to create my own disk image after I modify the contents of the card while it's booting. This would [involve backing up the MBR](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-copy-mbr/), which I would attempt via:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=~/Desktop/mbr.raw bs=512 count=1
```

I could then back up each partition one at a time to a separate file via:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=~/Desktop/sda1.raw bs=1m
dd if=/dev/sda2 of=~/Desktop/sda2.raw bs=1m
```

Is there any way to concatenate these files into a single image, or safely script `dd` to extract all of their contents to a single file in the first place? The size of the bootloader and OS partitions may change in the future, but they will always be contiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I did the following, which worked:

1. Use `fdisk -l /dev/sdc` to list all partitions on the SD card. Note the block size (usually 512) and the "count" (ie: number of blocks occupied) by the first partition
2. Define a variable, `blks`, as `count+1`.
3. Issue the command: `dd if=/dev/sdc of=~/my_image.img bs=512 count=${blks}`

Comment: Thank you, but why you add `1` to `count`?

Comment: Because he wants the first partition (`count` blocks) and the MBR (`1` block).

Answer (score 3):

Use a subshell like this:

```
(dd if=/dev/sda1 bs=1m; dd if=/dev/sda2 bs=1m) > ~/Desktop/sda1+2.raw
```

Or, if you want the 512 byte MBR in there as well (probably not the best idea), you could do:

```
(dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1; dd if=/dev/sda1 bs=1m; dd if=/dev/sda2 bs=1m) > ~/Desktop/MBR+sda1+2.raw
```

Comment: I tried the latter of the two, but when I attempt to write the output file back to the SD card, it's not recognizable.

Comment: I didn't really like the idea of mixing the MBR and parttions in one file anyway. How about if you read the MBR off the front of the raw file and put that back on the drive first, then put the rest on afterwards? `dd if=file.raw of=/dev/sd? bs=512 count=1` followed by `dd if=file.raw of=/dev/sd?1 bs=512 iseek=1`

Comment: I would go with the first suggestion with a separate MBR.